# Why is it not possible to use the dot operator (.) with `this` in C++?

Tags: c++

I would like to know why the use of `this.var` to access internal class variables does not work in my case. I have to resort to `Class::var` or make use of another way of changing my variables.

In my case this does work:

```
Vec3D::Vec3D(float x, float y, float z){
    Vec3D::x = x;
    Vec3D::y = y;
    Vec3D::z = z;
    Vec3D::label = "";
}
```

And so does this:

```
Vec3D::Vec3D(float x, float y, float z):
            x(x),y(y),z(z){}
```

However, if I try this:

```
Vec3D::Vec3D(float x, float y, float z){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.label = "";
}
```

then I get the error:

> expression must have class type but it has type "`N::Vec3D *`"

This is my class definition:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

namespace N {
    class Vec3D
    {
    protected:
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
        std::string label;
    public:
        //Constructors
        Vec3D(float x, float y, float z);
        Vec3D(float x, float y, float z, std::string label);
        Vec3D();
        void show();
     };
}
```

I would like to know what the cause is of the generated error and how I can improve myself.

Comment: `this` denotes a pointer. Try `this->`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `this` was added to C++ at a time well before references were added. So it was made a pointer. Otherwise `this` could instead have been a reference, and `this.var` *would* have been valid.

Answer (score 5):

It's because `this` is a pointer. So you need to use it like this: `this->x` instead of `this.x`.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that. Is the use of this. possible in c++ (like it is used in Java), or is it used for something completely different?

Comment: You can use `this->x` in c++.

Comment: No, in C++ the syntax is `this->`. Theoretically you could first dereference `this` and then use `.` to access the object's member like so `(*this).x` but this seems strange... In general, in C++, `this.x` doesn't make any sence from the point of view of syntax.

Comment: @RensV No, `this.` is not possible in C++. Raw pointers in C++ do not have a `.` operator. Generally, C++ and Java are different languages. Many principles and idioms in C++ are quite different from those in Java. You better learn proper C++ instead of trying to use it like Java.

Comment: @heap-underrun 
I thought so, its just that at the Uni we get thaught a lot of languages at the same time, so sometimes I mix them up by accident. I'm here to learn proper c++ as I feel that it is more powerfull than Java, when it is used correctly. Anyway thanks for your guidance, I'll do more research!

Comment: As a neat bit of trivia, the ability to control the type of `this` is [currently planned for C++23](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0847r7.html). which would make it possible to substitute `this->x` with something like `self.x`

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a pointer to the object, not a reference, nor is it a copy of the object.  If an object is behind a pointer, one has to *dereference* it with the prefix `*` operator before accessing its members with the `.` operator; more typically though, one uses the `->` operator to perform both at once.  C++ inherited this syntax from C, which in turn has it for [pretty tedious historical reasons](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/10812/15334).  Although in case of `this` specifically, it’s often not even necessary to explicitly mention it from within member functions, as the usual scoping rules will happily resolve bare names to the respective data or function members.

Compare:

```
#include <iostream>

struct point {
    float x;
    float y;

    void show() {
        // member functions can access data members without
        // explicitly referencing `this`
        std::cout << "(" << x << ", " << y << ")" << std::endl;
    }
};

void foo() {
    point p { 1, 1 };
    point &q = p;
    point *r = &p;

    // modifying p.x through a reference
    q.x = 42;

    // reading p.x through a pointer
    std::cout << r->x << std::endl;
    /*           ↑↑↑↑ equivalent to (*r).x */

    p.show();   // calling a member function on an owned value
    q.show();   // calling a member function through a reference
    r->show();  // calling a member function through a pointer
 /* ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ equivalent to (*r).show() */
}
```

In your example, `this` has type, `Vec3D *`, i.e. a pointer to `Vec3D`.  As such, it has to be used like `r` above, if you use it at all.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a pointer to an object belonging to the method you are writing. You must dereference that pointer in order to access the opject. Once you access the object, you can then call a method with the dot operator. The `->` operator is just a combo of the dereference operator (`*`) and the dot operator (`.`). Example:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo();

// This line
foo->bar();
// is equivalent to this line
(*foo).bar();
```

In the last line of the example, I first dereferenced the `foo` pointer with `*` to access the object. Then I used `.` to call a method on the object. The `->` does both the dereferencing and the calling of the method.